# documents' url & Virtual host - liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, document, liferay-6, virtualhost

We have a problem with links for download documents after adding a virtual host with **Liferay 6.2 CE GA1.**

- We have created an organization and a site attached.  For this site,
- We have added a virtual host ("intranet") for private pages.
- We have created a private page "Documents" with "Document & Media"
  portlet.

For access to this page, we can use

- default url : `localhost:8080/group/my_orga/documents/`
- url with virtual host : `intranet:8080/documents/`

These two urls work well.

With default url, the download link `(localhost:8080/documents/x/y/test.doc/...)` works.

But if we access from virtual host, the download link `(intranet:8080/documents/x/y/test.doc/...)` doesn't work and we get a 404 result.

How can we fix this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my reply in below Liferay Forum.

https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/35465626